# lucene vs sphinx vs xapian vs lemur , which is a good choice for production use?

Tags: full-text-search, sphinxsearch

I am evaluating the full-text searching systems and I really need your practical experiences. Also you can suggest some that I didn't mention.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 2):

#### Apache Solr

Solr is a standalone Enterprise Search Server.  It presents a web service layer built atop the [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) search library, extending it to provide application users with a ready-to-use search platform. Solr brings with it operational and administrative capabilities like web services, faceting, configurable schema, caching, replication, and administrative tools for configuration, data loading, statistics, logging, cache management, and more.

See the complete [feature list](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/features.html) for more details.

It's also worth reading:

1. [Lucene vs Solr](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-vs-solr.html)
2. [Pros & cons of full text search engine ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/737275/181870)
3. [Choosing a stand-alone full-text search server: Sphinx or SOLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1284083/181870)